# Header in Transformation File (SAP BPC) getting evaluated even when not desired

Tags: transformation, business-objects, flat, consolidation, sap-bw

I am facing an issue with my flat file.

**The BAdI is processing the header data as the body of the flat file.**

Due to this, the TIMEID, which is conditioned to be an year belonging to 'Q1', is giving the error.

If I replace the TIME label with 2014.Q1 (which belongs to Q1), then it works fine, but if I use the label “TIMEID” in the header data, it gets evaluated, and gives an error:

> time member TIMEID does not belong to Q1

This also rejects all the subsequent records. This happens regardless of whether HEADER in the transformation file is labeled as YES (with SKIP=1) or NO.

Due to this, the `cl_ujk_query=>query()` function is not returning any data.

Following is the flat file (`C` is for header data, and `R` is for the records, both of which are valid):

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  TIMEID  c7  c8  c8  c9
r11 r12 r13 r14 r15 2014.Q1 r17 r18 r19 r20
r21 r22 r23 r24 r25 2013.Q1 r27 r28 r29 r30
```

Following is the Transformation File:

```
*OPTIONS
FORMAT = DELIMITED
HEADER = YES
DELIMITER = ,
SKIP = 1
SKIPIF =
VALIDATERECORDS=YES
CREDITPOSITIVE=YES
MAXREJECTCOUNT= -1
ROUNDAMOUNT=
STARTROUTINE=ZNAME_TIME
*MAPPING
A=*COL(1)
B=*STR(OC_) + *COL(8)
TIME=*COL(6)
D=*STR(NOBUYER)
E=*STR(CC)
F=*STR(INPUT)
G=*COL(5)
H=*COL(2)
I=*COL(4)
J=*STR(NO_J)
K=*COL(7)
*CONVERSION
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the header = NO in the transformation file .

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. Could you expand upon it a little further?

Comment: [`HEADER=NO`](https://help.sap.com/docs/search?q=Transformation%20File%3A%20Options) indicates to process the first line of the data source i.e. it's not a header line. But the question author has said that it was a header line...